Перенос данных о записях из двух старых баз данных в одну новую основную
есть три базы данных, первая основная, другие две старые из которых нужно перенести только записи/посты новостей, пытался просто объединить данные из таблиц wp_posts через проверку ячейки post_type (если post_type = post, то данные переносятся), в одну общую, вроде всё ок, но записи не отображаются нигде, только в таблице остались и больше ничего. Может есть какой-то простой способ это сделать через wordpress или ещё как-то?

Стандартный WordPress экспор/импорт? Зачем это делать через БД?

сто лет не работал с WP, напомните как это делать

просто от старых данных есть только бд, нет развернутых на них wordpress
